# How to generate toString and hashCode methods honoring the checkstyle rules

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

Currently while automatically generating the equals and hashCode methods, Eclipse does not take the checkstyle rules into consideration and it generates the below code but with checkstyle error:

[image]

After that I need to manually fix the name of the variable and arguments as per checkstyle rule.

Is there any way to configure something in Eclipse so that it uses the checkstyle rules while generating automatic methods (name, parameter, local variable names)?

Thanks
Atul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to automatically comply to Checkstyle rules when generating code. Checkstyle and it's rules are are designed for verification. Without going into detail: Generation rules would have to be implemented differently which makes it technically impossible to just use those Checkstyle rules for that.

You can, however, change the generating templates in Eclipse yourself to be Checkstyle compliant. In the preferences in Java=>Editor=>Templates you can change some existing ones or add a new one. Sadly the equals/hashcode generation is not among them. Take a look at [How to customize hashCode() and equals() generated by Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255210/how-to-customize-hashcode-and-equals-generated-by-eclipse) to see how to do that.